# Swift package Manager canImport and weak framework

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I need a solution where I conditionally add logic to my framework only if the dependency is available. I don't want to force the user to add dependencies. For example:

```
struct MyClass {
   func doSomeWork(completion: (Result<Something, SomeError>) -> Void)
}

#if canImport(ReactiveSwift)
import ReactiveSwift

extension MyClass {
   func doSomeWork() -> SignalProducer<Something, SomeError>
}
#endif
```

is this possible with swift and SPM?

Comment: Doesn't this work as it is?